# How do I get the SVN rev corresponding to a git commit hash?

Tags: git, svn

So I'm using SVN to get a specific folder within a git repo by replacing `tree/main` with `trunk` but it's at the latest version.

How do I checkout the folder at a specific commit hash in Git, if I don't know the rev number?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `git-svn`? If so, commits that are in svn have an id (as part of the comment) that does provide the branch path in svn repo and the revision number. Just for kicks, here's one example of svn's mirror in github:

```
Fix issues #4911: external file pointing at redirected URL.
The fix is similar to r1525902, fixing external dir.

* subversion/libsvn_client/externals.c
  (handle_external_item_change):
    Pass the possibly redirected URL to switch_file_external(), not the old 
    one.



git-svn-id: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk@1908926 13f79535-47bb-0310-9956-ffa450edef68
```

So, path to the branch: `https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk`. Revision: `1908926`

Taken from https://github.com/apache/subversion/commit/fc6985f4da70da2a925426cd6c8e4cfb8d622a81

Just to expand a little bit: there is no equivalent between a git commit hash and svn revisions. svn revisions are sequential whereas git commits are product of a hash so it's not sequential.

Comment: So basically I don't have a svn repo that I'm pointing to. Assume the ONLY information I have is a github URL. For example: `https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/tree/master/docs`. Now, I replace `tree/master` with `trunk`. I checkout the url `https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/trunk/docs`. Now suppose I want to get a specific github commit hash using this method. I don't see a way to derive a SVN rev from a git hash.